# replaceEmpty not called

Tags: ios, combine

I am trying to understand the Combine Empty publisher and his impact on a subscriber. I have created a publisher which produces a stream of two values followed by `.append(Empty(completeImmediately: false))` and `replaceEmpty(with: 3)`. I don't understand why a value from `replaceEmpty` is not present in a sink receiveValue closure. I tried to set `true` to `completeImmediately` but it doesn't send a value from `replaceEmpty`. My question is: Why `replaceEmpty` is not called ?

```
[1,2].publisher
    .append(Empty(completeImmediately: false))
    .replaceEmpty(with: 3)
    .sink { completion in
        print(completion)
    } receiveValue: { value in
        print(value)
    }
```